# talend tGSCopy selective file copy to other bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, talend

Using Talend, I am trying to move an App engine data store backup file specifically **skiping** file name ends with ".backup_info" to new folder.

I have to load only file 2,3 skipping file 1.

File:1
ahFzfnZpcmdpbi1yZWQtdGVzdHJACxIcX0FFX0RhdGFzdG9yZUFkbWluX09wZXJhdGlvbhiRyH8MCxIWX0FFX0JhY2t1cF9JbmZvcm1hdGlvbhgBDA.backup_info

File:2
ahFzfnZpcmdpbi1yZWQtdGVzdHJACxIcX0FFX0RhdGFzdG9yZUFkbWluX09wZXJhdGlvbhiRyH8MCxIWX0FFX0JhY2t1cF9JbmZvcm1hdGlvbhgBDA.**MasterContentType.backup_info**

File#3    ahFzfnZpcmdpbi1yZWQtdGVzdHJBCxIcX0FFX0RhdGFzdG9yZUFkbWluX09wZXJhdGlvbhjSz7UDDAsSFl9BRV9CYWNrdXBfSW5mb3JtYXRpb24YAQw.**Timeline.backup_info**

There are around 100 objects, how do I key in for *"Source Object Key"* of tGScopy in component configuration to select particular file. This seems challenging, please assist.

Comment: I figured out an interim solution. Try use GSTUIL instead to do file manipulations.